# Particular software ENVI hangs 1 out of 4 times when it tries to bring up open/save file dialog

Tags: freeze

As far as I can see, other programs are working fine with file dialog. But this expensive image software ENVI hangs forever one out of four times when it tries to bring up open/save dialog. I know I have to work with its customer representatives, but they couldn't do anything last 2 years since we had this problem. Is there anyway to find what is wrong?

Comment: Does the software work fine on another machine? Have you reinstalled the OS at any time? The sysinternals tool [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor) should help you see what the program is doing to the registry and filesystem when it crashes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I found a solution to this problem by turning off network discovery after posting this question. I am not sure why only this software had the problem with the setting, but 4-hour-long experiment with the software revealed it finally fixed my problem. Here is what I did to turn off the setting.

1. Open the *Network and Sharing Center*.
2. On the left side, click on *Change advanced sharing settings*.
3. Click on *Domain(current profile)* and then select *Turn off network discovery*.
4. Save it and close.